# Doctrine schema diff -- no objects

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I am looking for a way to auto generate migrations by comparing dev to a staging environment. These migrations will then be applied automatically when pushed to staging environment

Doctrine has a nice migration module but for the life of me cannot figure it out. Seems it uses the entities to build the migrartions which in my case own't work -- as I am only using the DBAL at this time.

I suppose I will look for a lower-lvele tool to analyze two database and generate me the raw SQL to migrarte up or down -- any suggestions?

Comment: If you are not using doctrine entities, then there is no way doctrine migrations can be used. Since you are looking for a generic database migration/version control mechanism, your question should be reworded to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably talk a look at this awesome list: https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#migrations